# How to calculate a correlation coefficient in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'd like to see if there is a correlation between two turtle variables after a number of ticks. So we've got turtles-own [a b], and do they correlate after 100 ticks?

I can export these and do the calculation in a spreadsheet, but it seems it should be easier to have NetLogo do it, and maybe even simpler to use the regress feature of the matrix extension (regress a on b and output the beta coefficient).

But I can't figure out how to create a matrix made up of two columns, all the a and b values from the turtles.

So:

1. does anyone have some ready-made code to calculate the Pearson coefficient?
2. how do you create a matrix of turtle variables?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

See the `stats` NetLogo extension (https://github.com/cstaelin/Stats-Extension)

**Example:**

Use the extension:

```
extensions [ stats ]
```

Turtle setup:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  crt 5 [ fd 10 ]
end
```

Calculation:

```
to go
  ; Create some data as nested list (two variables for each turtle):
  let data [(list xcor ycor)] of turtles

  ; Create a stats table:
  let tbl stats:newtable-from-row-list data

  ; Calculate a correlation matrix with `stats:correlation`:
  let cor-list stats:correlation tbl

  ; In 2x2 case you can use the second element from the first row to get the coefficient:

  print item 0 item 1 cor-list
end
```

### Using matrix

Use matrix extension:

```
extensions [ matrix ]
```

Create a  matrix:

```
; data is same nested list as in previous example
let m matrix:from-row-list data

; apply linear regression model
let m-reg matrix:regress m

; there is R^2 in the first element of the second element of `m-reg`
print item 0 item 1 m-reg
```

Note that `stats:correlation` calculates R and `matrix:regress` calculates R^2.